# Meteor: Replace deanius:promise with okgrow:promise

Tags: meteor, coffeescript, promise

my app was using deaunius:promise package for promises, now it is deprecated, and I have to translate all my promises to the syntax of okfrow:promise package, I was trying to understand how to create meteor Promises with that package and how to translate my current Promises to the new package but Im not sure how to do it in the proper way, it is quite different for me...

This is one example of a promise I used to write with deanius:promise

```
Meteor.promise('sendSubmission', null, submission) 
        .then( (result) ->
            FlashMessages.sendSuccess "Successfully Finished the Test"
            Router.go 'submissionView', _id: result.submissionId
        ).catch (error) ->
            FlashMessages.sendError error.reason
            Router.go 'takeTest', slug: currentTest.slug
```

How to write the above promise using okgrow:promise package? the examples they provide are not helpful at all for me. Thanks for your help

Comment: What is going wrong with what you currently have?

Comment: It just stopped working, in the console it says "Object #<Object> has no method 'promise'", and in the JavaScript console it says "deanius:promise is deprecated. Please replace deanius:promise with okgrow:promise in .meteor/packages" I already installed okgrow:promise package but it still shows the same error

Comment: did you also remove deanus:promise after adding okgrow promise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my app was using deaunius:promise package for promises, now it is deprecated

That wording seems to be unfortunate. Instead of being "deprecated", I'd have said "moved" - nothing really changed but the repository; it's still maintained by the same contributor. The code is just a fork, much of it is probably still the same.

> I have to translate all my promises to the syntax of okfrow:promise package

No. The API has not changed a bit. All you would need to do is update the name of your dependency.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean with "all you would need to do is update the name of your dependency"" right now my promises do not work it says "Object #<Object> has no method 'promise'"

Comment: I don't know Meteor, but somewhere you imported `deaunius:promise`. Now you need to import `okgrow:promise` instead, and the rest of your code should continue to work as it is..

Comment: Yea you were right I just replaced the old one with the new one and everything is working now.